# Qt seems to use lots of threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt

I have used Qt quite a lot, but recently needed to debug the threads I have been creating and found many more threads then I was expecting.

So my program is a simple console only (no GUI) Qt application (linux).

Threads that I have created:

- It has a main() (which executes the QtCoreApplication) - so that is the main thread.
- A thread to process received data from the com port (using FTDI D2XX thirdparty code drivers)

And that is all. When I do ps -T... and find my application there are 7 threads. I have two classes that are QObjects using signals and slots, so maybe they need a thread each for message handling, that takes me to 4 threads... so I am at a loss as to why I might have 7 threads for my application.

Can anyone explain more about what is going on? can post code if needed. Note I only use `new QThread` once in my code (for the moment).

Comment: I can't imagine why Qt would create additional threads without being asked to, especially without GUI, but maybe he's not the culprit. Try to disable the creation of your thread, perhaps the FTDI driver created the other 3.

Comment: Also AFAIK signals+slots for normal events like button clicks won't require extra threads. They are handled in the event loop.

Comment: Qt applications do spawn a whole lotta threads, especially GUI applications.

Comment: @FabioCeconello This is true, but provides wrong impression. The "normal" adjective is unnecessary. There is no such thing as "non-normal" events. Also, the signal-slot mechanism and events are two completely different things.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Um, no. Well, Qt doesn't do it, the user code is certainly free to, though.

Comment: @KubaOber: I'm talking about an empty GUI application. Literally empty, just the main window with no user code. That's 7 threads. And once you start using QtNetwork, or QtMultimedia, or QFileSystemWatcher, or OpenGL, that number goes way up.

Comment: @KubaOber you're right, I was missing the right word there. By "normal" I meant "the usual". And that's just because I can't claim to have used the entirety of Qt and affirm that a thread would never be needed. Didn't understand about the second part, though. Isn't a, say, mouse click a GUI event? And isn't it handled by a signal+slot?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe What Qt version and what platform? Have you confirmed that these threads are started by Qt and not the libraries it depends on?

Comment: @FabioCeconello Events are handled by the event dispatcher calling `QObject::event`. What has that got to do with signals and slots I wouldn't know. Of course the (re)implementation of `event` is free to send a signal, but that's a completely separate matter.

Comment: @KubaOber: Windows, Qt 5.5.1. I have no idea which specific code started the threads, and I couldn't care less as it's induced by Qt either way.

Comment: "I have no idea which specific code started the threads [...] it's induced by Qt either way." You can't be serious, I hope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt doesn't create any per-`QObject` threads. It creates helper threads for some plaform-specific reasons, e.g. `QProcess` sometimes needs helper threads.

The FTDI D2XX unix driver uses libusb and that implementation is completely backwards and uses additional threads on top of the thread you've provided for it. Frankly said, you shouldn't be using the D2XX driver on Linux or OS X. Just use the kernel driver.

You should simply run the D2XX driver in a trivial non-Qt test application that opens the device and reads from it continuously and see how many threads it spawns. You'll be dismayed...

Comment: omg, you're right! - the D2XX adds three threads on its own!, I really was not expecting that else I would have isolated that in a test as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @code_fodder Worse yet: every bit of data you send to the device or get back from it is passed through one or two worker threads in the userland driver/libusb. It forces context switches and is abysmally slow if you're transferring slow chunks of data often. FTDI's approach to this is horrible, and libusb doesn't do anyone any favors either. Don't use that wretched piece of (*censored*).

Comment: @code_fodder Since I can't edit the comment: s/every bit/every chunk/ of data [...] s/slow chunks/small chunks/. I can't type today.

Comment: ... ummm, but I understood all your comments :) ... just not that last one with the `s/every....` what does all that mean?    Also, I have changed to using the tty (or VCD kernel) driver... much better :)))

Comment: sed command: s/before/after/ means replace "before" with "after" :)

Comment: lol, ok I see what you saying :) ... I am not very "sed" savvy!