# Using FTDI D2xx.DLL with Qt on Android

Tags: android, qt, serial-port, ftdi

I developed a software on Mac OSX  using Qt5.6 Creator and a FTDI USB-to-Serial chip, FT232R. The software detects, reads and writes to the serial port on Mac and PC(windows) successfully. In both cases, FT232R is installed as a virtual com port. My next task is to port it to Android. I have a smartphone running Android 4.2.

I knew that FTDI made a D2xx driver for Android without the need of rooting. I ran the demo app, FTDIUART Terminal v1.1 successfully too. But my problem is, I am missing the building blocks in between. I downloaded the source code of the demo app and found out that Qt could not open it.

Would someone please tell me how to use D2xx driver in Qt on Mac or PC and then deploy to Android?  Any hints would help.

Thank you
Sky

Comment: Hi. Did you have any problems getting Qt to see the USB/serial port on Mac? I have a similar adapter (a Prolific), but the Qt serial enumeration example does not see it; it only sees Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 1):

So for PC (using linux) you need the d2xx library files and the header files and then add them into your project. Here is an example of the things you may need to add to your .pro file:

```
// If you store the ftdi files (headers) in a ftdi sub-dir:
INCLUDEPATH += ftdi

// Include the ftdi headers
HEADERS  += ftdi/ftd2xx.h \
            ftdi/WinTypes.h

// Include the libraries - this is for deployment - take a copy of the files to deploy with your project. You don't really need this, it's just what I was using...
OTHER_FILES += lib/libftd2xx.a \
               lib/libftd2xx.so.1.3.6

// Link to the library itself "/usr/local/libftd2xx.a" - ensure you have copied the lib files here (or somewhere similar).
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lftd2xx
```

There is example code and documentation to use this driver on the web site: http://www.ftdichip.com/. As a start point the first function you can try is: FT_ListDevices(...) to generate a list of USB serial ports that are available.

Comment: Thanks code_fodder. I will try it on a PC or Mac. But my follow up question will be, Android is using a Java D2XX driver. How to deploy such a driver together with the apt to the device? How to know the directories to put in the .pro file?

Comment: @DLiu I can guide you for the PC version of this, but I have not used android. If its python based you might want to look at pyqt

Comment: Thank you for your offer. Let me dig into it more thoroughly esp. on the Android part first..  I used Ecilpse to open the FTDI demo software and was able to read the logic. But I do not know how to port it to Qt.  I don't want to rewrite the code in Eclipse again. I may contact you for your help if everything in vain...  Cheers

Comment: @DLiu ok np. BTW - if you can avoid using D2XX I would its pretty poor on linux and OS X. Take a look at Kuba's answer to my question here for some more details on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902218/qt-seems-to-use-lots-of-threads

Comment: How can I create a .pro file that will build with support for libftd2xx for Linux and Windows ? Also does using libftd2xx on Android need root permissions ? Lates I could find is 1.4.6 for ARMV5 soft-float which should run basically on any Android phone http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm